# Added Project to Group on GitLab, now "cannot read from remote repository"

Tags: gitlab

I just added an existing project to a new Group on GitLab; how should I update my local repository's details so I can access my GitLab repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should change the url of the project:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://<gitlab.server>/<group>/<project>
# or, if you are using ssh, assuming user git:
git remote set-url origin git@<gitlab.server>:<group>/<project>
```

Try a `git ls-remote origin` to check this is working.